# Embedding Ruby and compiling

Tags: c, ruby, makefile

How do you compile a C application with Ruby embedded?

What's the `-l` flag? Is there something else that i'm missing (linking to an exact ruby version)

Comment: It's exactly as you feel: Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding a language usually links the interpreter with the binary that embeds it, `-l` links a library with the program, you could try:

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ myprog.c -o myprog -lruby
```

Note you may need to include this too, or similar on your platform:

```
-I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux/
```